# Login disallowed for security reasons postgresql centos server

Tags: apache, security, authentication, centos, phppgadmin

I am configuring my centos server. I installed `postgresql` and `phppgadmin`

When i try accessing phppgadmin as `my_server_ip/phpPgAdmin`

It redirects to login page and when i try to login getting error as

`Login disallowed for security reasons`

I even change `extra_login_security` to `false` and restarted using following commands

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

and

```
service postgresql-9.2 restart
```

Can anyone help me.

Comment: what log messages do you see?

Answer (score 83):

1). Open -> /etc/phppgadmin -> config.inc.php

2). change `$conf['extra_login_security'] = true;`    to   `$conf['extra_login_security'] = false;`

> // If extra login security is true, then logins via phpPgAdmin with no
>   // password or certain usernames (pgsql, postgres, root,
>   administrator) // will be denied. Only set this false once you have
>   read the FAQ and // understand how to change PostgreSQL's pg_hba.conf
>   to enable // passworded local connections.

Comment: Fixed for me while integrating postgres and phppgadmin with wamp on windows.

Comment: Why would one expect to not be able to login to phppgadmin right after installing it? Seems counter intuitive?

Comment: @Ruraj using this only certain usernames (pgsql, postgres, root, administrator) will be denied. or usernames without any password

Comment: Could be that you have to restart postgresql and apache2 before this applies. Not sure though, I could not test it. https://bobcares.com/blog/login-disallowed-for-security-reasons-phppgadmin-error-how-we-fix-it/. In my case, even that did not help, there was no reaction at any pw entry. I could not get access to my definitely running server that I had built according to https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/ubuntu-postgresql-installation/, I guess Phppgadmin is replaced by Adminer and the trick does not work anymore?

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem - also on CentOS - and also had no luck changing that security setting to false.

It turned out that it's not using the config file we expected.

---

It's using:
/usr/share/phpPgAdmin/conf/config.inc.php

and not:
/etc/phpPgAdmin/config.inc.php

---

even though the RPM (phpPgAdmin-5.1-1.rhel6.noarch) installs both of them...

I really don't see why it has two unless there is an override defined somewhere... but I don't really have time to look into it. I'm sure there is no reason why you can't replace the one in /etc with a symlink (or hardlink) to the other, although it could cause problems if you try to uninstall the RPM. But I wouldn't unless you were dead keen to have it in /etc - just in case. I'm sure they didn't include two of these just for fun ;)

I know this is probably too late to help you but the fact I came across this today means it's likely to be of use to *someone* :)

Answer (score -1):

You need to restart the postgresql

systemctl restart postgresql

systemctl restart apache2